# VBA Excel chart in User form error - Compiler Error- Argument not optional

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to write a program that gets the values from an excel spreadsheet and puts them into a chart on a userform. I'm using Excel 2011, and I've downloaded a copy of Microsoft OWC 10.0 to allow the addition of a chart. My code is below:

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim M As Integer
Dim N As Integer

With UserForm1.ChartSpace1

```
M = .Charts.Count
If M = 0 Then GoTo COMEHERE Else GoTo Finish
```

COMEHERE:
    .Charts.Add
        With .Charts(0)
            ' Create a bar chart.
            .Type = chChartTypeXYScatterLine

```
           ' Add data series to the chart.

            N = .SeriesCollection.Count
            If N = 0 Then GoTo COMEHERE1 Else GoTo Finish
```

COMEHERE1:

```
            .SeriesCollection.Add
        'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = 1 ' test to check how far program gets


        ' Set the properties of the first data series.
          With .SeriesCollection(0)
            .SetData chDimSeriesNames = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
            .SetData chDimXValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A12").Value
            .SetData chDimYValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B12").Value

           End With
           .HasLegend = True
```

Finish:

```
        End With
```

End With
End Sub

The M and N integers are a hangover from originally writing the code as private sub ChartSpace1_Click(), where I'd get a new chart and series every time I clicked the mouse. The values in columns A3:A12 and B3:B12 are simply 1 to 10

When the code gets to the .setData function, it falls over (Compiler Error - Argument not optional). I've seen similar examples of this code online where people have apparently gotten around this, but I couldn't figure it out or get their code to work.

The purpose for this code is to go into a larger program that I'm writing to show various scientific graphs based on user inputs.

ANy help that people have would be greatly appreciated

J

Comment: Your use of setData is incorrect.  See example here for some guidance: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235885/EN-US

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response - Unfortunately it doesn't help too much as the .datasource command being used here appears to not be compatible with OWC charts. I found something online (http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?7760-Solved-Graph-inside-a-userform) where the solution appeared to be to insert a OWC spreadsheet into the work book, copy values out of the active workbook and paste into the OWC spreadsheet, and plot from that. Modifying the code from that website I was able to get the program working

Answer (score 0):

You may find this approach to be much easier: [Displaying A Chart In A Userform](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/displaying_a_chart_in_a_userform/). No need for OWC or other added libraries. It's written for a Windows version of Excel, but you can probably figure out how to make it work on a Mac.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for the link. I had previously came across a post by you suggesting this method, and yes it would be much easier, but I'm trying to design the entire macro so its "self sufficient" and can easily run on any other computer (with Excel and VBA). The program is intended to do some 1D geophysical modelling, and there are several userforms worth of inputs and outputs, with several charts.

J

Comment: I would think saving a gif of a chart and using it as the picture of an image control would be more portable than hoping OWC is present and would work on any computer.

Comment: Hi John, Your probably right. However, I've decided to re-programme the whole thing in VB as an executable file, and charts (seem) to be handled better in VB. Also, the program seems less buggy and runs faster by storing the data for the charts in a database table rather than accessing it from excel.